# How to Flag Holiday Shifts Year Over Year (YoY)

Tags: r

To give you a little bit of context. I am attempting to create an event calendar that would control for recurring events such as Holidays (mainly US holidays).

I would also like to flag shifts in days (weeks, months or even quarters) YoY of said holidays. Easter for instance falls in quarter one in 2024 while falling in quarter two the subsequent year (2025). Below is my attempt at transposing this logic into code (which works for only YoY figures between current year and next year- or prior year). The column that needs work is 
"ShiftInHoliday".

How can one dynamically flag a shift in holidays such that the aforementioned shift in Easter can be recorded in the dataset for all future dates and compared to prior years as well ?

```
if (!require(timeDate)) install.packages("timeDate", quiet = TRUE)
if (!require(dplyr)) install.packages("dplyr", quiet = TRUE)

currentYear <- getRmetricsOptions("currentYear")
mainly_us_holidays <- subset(listHolidays(), grepl("US|CA|FR|GB|CaR", listHolidays()) == TRUE)
all <- c(mainly_us_holidays, c("Easter", "EasterSunday", "EasterMonday"), mainly_us_holidays)

holiday_mapped <- 
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(all, function(i){
            foo <- match.fun(i)  
            data.frame(all = i,
                       dates = as.Date(foo(2017:2030)))

          }))

holiday_mapped$all <- 
  ifelse(substr(holiday_mapped$all, 1, 2) %in% c("CA") | substr(holiday_mapped$all, 1, 3) %in% c("CaR"), paste0("Canada:", holiday_mapped$all),
         ifelse(substr(holiday_mapped$all, 1, 2) %in% "FR", paste0("France:", holiday_mapped$all),
                ifelse(substr(holiday_mapped$all, 1, 2) %in% "GB", paste0("Great Britain:",holiday_mapped$all),
                       paste0("US:", holiday_mapped$all ))))

holiday_mapped <- holiday_mapped %>% group_by(all) %>% arrange(all) %>% mutate(dateDiff_Holiday = diff(c(NA, dates)))

holiday_mapped$HolidayShiftFlag <- ifelse(abs(holiday_mapped$dateDiff_Holiday) %% 365 %in% c(0, 1, c(359:364, 366:371)), 0,
                                  ifelse(holiday_mapped$all == "Non-Holiday", 0, ifelse(is.na(holiday_mapped$dateDiff_Holiday) == TRUE, 0, 1)))


holiday_mapped$ShiftInHoliday <- 
  ifelse( holiday_mapped$HolidayShiftFlag == 1 & (holiday_mapped$dateDiff_Holiday - 365) < 0,
          paste(holiday_mapped$all, "Shifts", abs(holiday_mapped$dateDiff_Holiday - 365), "Days Backward", "|", 
          round(abs(holiday_mapped$dateDiff_Holiday - 365) / 7, 2), "Weeks"),
          ifelse(holiday_mapped$HolidayShiftFlag == 1 & (holiday_mapped$dateDiff_Holiday - 365) > 0, paste(holiday_mapped$all, "Shifts",
          abs(holiday_mapped$dateDiff_Holiday - 365), "Days Forward", "|", round((abs(holiday_mapped$dateDiff_Holiday - 365)) / 7, 2), "Weeks"), NA ))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: FYI, I think this line of code is wrong: `if (!require(dplyr)) install.packages("timeDate", quiet = TRUE)` ... check dplyr and install timeDate?

Comment: yes it was thank you for pointing it out !

Answer (score 0):

I was over-complicating things. I simply reused the diff() function using base R but this time on days and weeks to get a YoY shifts in days and weeks (-Months and Quarters become inferred). Thank you for your time for those who gave it an attempt !